# How to delete attachment from the attachment object array inside another comment object array which is inside another object array

Tags: angular, typescript, object

I would like to remove an attachment from the array of attachment objects which is inside another array of comment objects which is inside of another object array. I have been struggling with the solution.

```
export class CommentSection{
  id: string;
  comments: CommentObject[];
}
```

```
export class CommentObject{
  id: string;
  created: Date;
  text: string;
  attachments: CommentAttachment[];
}
```

```
export class CommentAttachment{
  id: string;
  created: Date;
  filename: string;
}
```

And my ts file with draft solution, which is not working (not deleting attachment):

```
export class CommentsComponent {

  public comment: CommentObject;
  commentsArray: CommentSection;

  public deleteCommentAttachment(attachment: CommentAttachment): void {
    this.commentsArray.comments = this.commentsArray.comments.filter((c) =>
      c[this.comment.id].attachments.splice(attachment.id, 1),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to filter the attachments not the comments right? Also splice is working with indexes not custom id-s. Ive replaced filter with map. Have not tested it but it should work:)

```
this.commentsArray.comments = this.commentsArray.comments.map((c) => {
    const comment = c[this.comment.id];
    const attachments = comment.attachments;
    const index = attachments.findIndex(at => at.id == attachment.id);
    attachments.splice(index, 1);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to modify the code if I get an error: Type 'void[]' is not assignable to type 'CommentObject[]'?

Comment: I dont see that code in your example, but this generly means something expects type CommentObject[] and you return void[] (nothing). First option is to correct the two types and return proper one. Second option is to use return type any

Answer (score 2):

You may also transform into rxjs to do it in readable steps, although some may find it as overkill. Here is the example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-swnhf1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts